# Using multiple language views for the same controller in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

How do I use multiple language views in a controller according to the url parameter?
I have a english version of a website in CodeIgniter.I want to make Greek and Arabic version of this website without changing the models and controllers.Anybody know how to do it so that i can get CodeIgniter to display different views for the same controller according to the language parameters in the URL. like the URL below

http://www.example.com/en/  for English

http://www.example.com/ar/  for Arabic

http://www.example.com/gk/  for Greek

Thanks in advance

Comment: please mark the correct answer as accepted, or provide further information if you need further help.. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try with this:

**[Internationalization (i18n) library for CodeIgniter](http://maestric.com/doc/php/codeigniter_i18n)**

I've used it in my project with little modification and it is really great.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I need to use different templates(views) for each language because my design have images with text in different languages.So using a language file does't work.

Comment: You don't have to use language files, they are for static text (leave them blank)... you can take all (sentences, paragraph, text in general) from database (I used both approaches in my application, but you can stick only to database).
About the views, make one master template and depending on language load your language dependent views (with those images) if those pages are dynamic. If they are static pages then its even easier.
This library will help you to route to appropriate language more easily, nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to do the following, if you have different templates/views for each language.

```
$lang = $this->uri->segment(1);

$this->load->view("view_folder/".$lang."/main_page");
```

Then you can store each different languages like this:

```
view_folder/en/main_page.php
view_folder/ar/main_page.php
view_folder/gk/main_page.php
```

Please keep in mind to edit the routes, so you can use the same controller. I would use Regex in the routing system, like this:

```
$route['([a-z_A-Z]+)/controller'] = 'controller';
```

Then when you do http://www.example.com/en/controller , you should be redirected to the controller and `$this->uri->segment(1);` will be available for language selection.